# Mapstruct convert object field to type as string + value.toString()

Tags: serialization, mapping, mapstruct

In Java, we have this beautiful library Mapstruct.
I'm wondering whether it can **map field to field type name + field value.toString()**.
Let's say I have two classes ConvertFrom and ConvertTo.

```
public class ConvertFrom {
    private String strValue;
    private Long longValue;
}

public class ConvertTo {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> result;
}
```

I'd like mapstruct to convert the field strValue and longValue to **type as string + value.toString()**.
So the implementation I'd expect the mapstruct to create is something like this:

```
public class ConvertFromToConvertToMapper {

    public ConvertTo toDto(ConvertFrom convertFrom) {
        ConvertTo convertTo = new ConvertTo();

        Field[] fields = ConvertFrom.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (Objects.nonNull(field.get(convertFrom))) {
                    convertTo.getResult().put(field.getName(), Map.of(field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.get(convertFrom)));
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return convertTo;
    }
}
```

Is it possible with the mupstruct?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

1. Create a class that maps ConvertFrom to Map and make it Spring Bean.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public class ConvertFromToConvertToMapper {

    public static Map<String, Map<String, ?>> toMapDto(ConvertFrom convertFrom) {
        Map<String, Map<String, ?>> result = new HashMap<>();
        Field[] fields = ConvertFrom.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (Objects.nonNull(field.get(convertFrom))) {
                    result.put(field.getName(), Map.of(field.getType().getSimpleName(), field.get(convertFrom)));
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

2. Use the created mapper whenever I want to map ConvertFrom to Map.
   E.g. if I have Dto that has ConvertFrom field like this

```
public class GeneralConvertFrom {
    private ConvertFrom convertFrom;
}
```

My mapper would look like this

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = ConvertFromToConvertToMapper.class)
public interface GeneralConvertFromToConvertToMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "result", source = "convertFrom")
    ConvertTo toDto(GeneralConvertFrom entity);
}
```

Saying this I didn't find the way to do it without writing mapper ConvertFromToConvertToMapper by myself.